# Executing Minecraft Server Commands via SSH and Screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, ssh, java

I'm extremely new to linux, so please help me out if you can! I have read many of the posts about managing/monitoring servers using SSH and Screen, but have not found anything regarding my particular issue yet. Here is what I have running:

Ubuntu 14.04 running Minecraft Server 1.8.3 .jar
I set up a separate user "minecraft" and added that user the the "minecraft" group and gave that ownership over my Minecraft folder. However, after doing this, I could copy my "World" file to the Minecraft server folder, so I added myself to the "minecraft" group. This seemed to work.

I installed Screen and openSSH to run the MC server. I run the server by starting a new Screen session named "minecraft"

My problem:
When I attach to the screen session directly from the PC, the commands in the MC server work just fine (`list`, `stop`, etc.). But when I connect to this screen session remotely via SSH from my work Mac, I'm not able to execute any of the commands. The text prints in the screen session window when typed directly, or when typed using a screen command such as `screen -S minecraft -p 0 -X stuff "stop^M"`, but nothing happens. The server does not output any response to these commands, and doesn't shut down when issued the "stop" command.

**New info:**
I reinstalled Ubuntu, restoring my admin privileges, and all was going well, but I had the same issue again. I logged in via SSH to my minecraft user directly and created a screen session running my minecraft server. But when I got home and connected to the screen session via Putty, I could once again not execute the minecraft server commands. I couldn't even stop the server. Does this issue have to do with the privileges of the user who is explicitly logged in to Ubuntu at the time of creation? Please help!

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, did you ever solve the issue?

Comment: Try using tmux instead. Worked for me.